# fill missing values in dataframe only when they are between two same values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a patient dataset with missing values. These missing values occur between two important events. The dataset is as below

I only need to fill up the missing rows if the upper event and the lower event matches.
if the upper event is "No response" and the lower event is "No response", I need to fill up the missing values in between as "No response". However, there are cases when these two dont correspond or the lower/upper event itself is also missing. Is there any ways how can I code this in python?

ps. there will only be 5 types of events if this is helpful. Thanks in advance

**AS-IS**

row 1    "No response"

row 2    "NA"

row 3    "No response"

row 4    "NA"

row 5    "Bad Response"

**TO-BE**

row 1    "No response"

row 2    "No response"

row 3    "No response"

row 4    "NA"

row 5    "Bad Response"

Comment: Please create a [mre]. I tried putting your example as an image but it is unnecessarily long

Comment: Please add more data in case your motive is to handle responses other than "No response"

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without dataset, but I think this can help you --

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(subset=["col1", "col2"], how="all")

#This will replace values in first arg with values in second arg, and can be lists .. 
#can also be ran on individual columns either with this or just called on series.

df.replace([np.nan,range(0,20)],[0,10]) #Think ranges work as well
```

could also use pd.date_range(beg,end), or a loc call depending how it's indexed.

```
#loc example
df.loc[df['col'].isin(list_of_values),column_list] = new_value
```

Though this would need to be done by each range of numbers or column.

Answer (score 0):

For the data given above you can try this

```
condition = (df['column_name'].shift().eq("No response") & df['column_name'].shift(-1).eq("No response"))

df.loc[condition, 'column_name'] = "No response"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this worked for me. Using ffill and bfill and checking the commons. Leaving the answer in case someone is looking for the same problem

def fill_between_na(df,col):
    """fill missing values that are between two particular events
    Args:
        df: DataFrame
        col: column name
    Returns:
        df: DataFrame with missing values filled
    """

```
whole_col=[]
patients_list= list(df.groupby("PATIENT_ID")['PATIENT_ID'].apply(lambda x: list(np.unique(x))[0]))
patients_grouped= df.groupby("PATIENT_ID")


for patient in patients_list:
    sub_group= patients_grouped.get_group(patient)
    sub_list=[]
    bfill_list= list(sub_group[col].fillna(method='bfill'))
    ffill_list= list(sub_group[col].fillna(method='ffill'))

    for i,val in enumerate(bfill_list):
        if val == ffill_list[i]:
            sub_list.append(val)
        else:
            sub_list.append(np.nan)
    whole_col.extend(sub_list)


df[col]= whole_col
return df
```